# Running Shiny App Freezing R Terminal in VScode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, shiny

I'm trying to work with basic shiny apps in vscode after coming from RStudio and I keep running into an issue where running any shiny app causes my R terminal session to freeze; after running the example I'm unable to type anything in the terminal unless I kill and reopen another R terminal. Any troubleshooting help would be great as I'm very new to vscode!

Reprex:

```
shiny::runExample("01_hello")
```

Terminal Output:

```
r$> shiny::runExample("01_hello")
Loading required package: shiny
Warning: package 'shiny' was built under R version 4.1.1

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4789
Browsing http://127.0.0.1:4789
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. In your R terminal, type the following:

   options(shiny.port = 7777)
2. In your shiny app, change the port to 7777:

   shinyServer(port = 7777)
3. Run your shiny app again and see if it works.

Comment: Strangely enough it looks like hitting ctrl + c actually lets me interact with the current terminal session without killing it; not sure what the underling error is but it looks like it's solved my issue. Thanks for the suggestions!